# How to enable and disable GUI as need for each boot it to save RAM resources?

Tags: gui, configuration, performance, desktop-environments, system

For an old PC Desktop with 4GB of RAM based on 64bits. For experimental purposes - I want install `Ubuntu` **Desktop** - mostly for two purposes:

- Server purpose.
- Use the DVD reader/writer to do backup anytime (it is the reason to use the `Desktop` environment)

**Note**

This PC is going to be accessed mostly through `SSH` and only in person when a backup through the DVD writer is need it.

**Goal**

Therefore to save resources mostly of RAM - I want load Ubuntu *by default* as **server** environment - thus *without* GUI - until the GUI be need it to use it, it to work with `Brasero`.

I read the following tutorial and seems viable

- [How to disable/enable GUI on boot in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux Desktop](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-enable-gui-on-boot-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop)

I am OK, if is need it do a reboot to change the type of environment from non-GUI to GUI and vice versa. It has sense to reflect the new settings.

My concern and

**Question**

- Is it the best approach to accomplish my goal? The use of the `systemctl` command?

I am assuming that when Ubuntu is loaded without GUI - as *server* - therefore at least 1GB to 1.5GB is not consumed because the GUI environment was not loaded from the beginning. Am I correct?

I did do this assumption because through VirtualBox for many VM I did do realize through `htop` command that Ubuntu Server saves 1/1.5GB of RAM against Ubuntu Desktop - but because here Ubuntu Desktop is used from the beginning and only by enable/disable the GUI - the expected behavior would be different

Comment: I am assuming that when Ubuntu is loaded without GUI - as server - therefore at least 1GB to 1.5GB is not consumed because the GUI environment was not loaded from the beginning. Am I correct? Please give a link there I can find this claim. Once you have installed a GUI it is there you can not just remove it and then call it as needed. You do not need to use it all the time but what you are describing would require physically removing and reinstalling the GUI each time you want to use it.

Comment: You can install a lightweight gui without all the desktop apps that installing a standard desktop includes. Lightweight Desktop environment
Ubuntu Server + lxde or openbox or fluxbox

Comment: @David did you read the latest paragraph of the OP?

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the feedback, I am going to do a research about them

Comment: AFAIK if you disable (via systemctl) your desktop manager (gdm, lightdm, etc.) after a reboot you should be dropped in a TTY with all the non-GUI stuff working in the background. And when you need the desktop, you can start the desktop manager manually. After you are done with the desktop, just restart the server, and it should go back to an only TTY server. (I know this from 1. When i've borked my desktop environment multiple times, 2. On Arch Linux, you can refuse to install a desktop manager and manually start your desktop environment every single time)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can disable the GUI while the server is up:

- Disable GUI by `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user` followed
  by reboot!
- To reenable temporarily (till the next reboot **only**)
  do `sudo systemctl start gdm3`
- To reenable permanently (all
  the time like the default) do `sudo systemctl set-default graphical` then reboot!